# Converting an ISO 8601 timestamp into an NSDate: How does one deal with the UTC time offset?

Tags: nsdate, utc, iso

I'm having trouble converting an **ISO 8601** timestamp into an `NSDate`.  I tried to use `NSDateFormatter`, but I can't get it to work with the **UTC** time offset that appears on the end of the timestamps.  To explain, I would like to convert a timestamp such as the following into an `NSDate`: `2011-03-03T06:00:00-06:00`.  My question is: How do I deal with the "-06:00" part?  I tried using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` as my date format string but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the code.  I have had some success.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, don't forget to set the `locale`. See Apple [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 63):

No need to remove the :'s. To handle the "00:00" style timezone, you just need "ZZZZ":

**Swift**

```
let dateString = "2014-07-06T07:59:00Z"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSString *input = @"2013-05-08T19:03:53+00:00";
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"]; //iso 8601 format
NSDate *output = [dateFormat dateFromString:input];
NSLog(@"Date output: %@", output);
```

Comment: This is like the 100th time I am searching for date short codes. I wish there is a site where I can just enter a date and it will automatically generate a date format string.

Comment: If you provide both Swift and Obj-C snippets, it'd be nice if they actually did the same thing. Here for example the Obj-C bit doesn't set the locale.

Comment: Additionally you may want to set dateFormat.timezone to eg. `    dateFormat.timeZone = [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:@"UTC"];
` to output the timestamp in Zulu

Answer (score 18):

In my case I received something like that:

"2015-05-07T16:16:47.054403Z"

And I had to use:

"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSZ"

Comment: I was getting dates that look like `2017-08-05T15:24:00.000Z` this format worked for me after all the others has failed

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `:` character inside the timezone offset.  You could explicitly remove just that colon, or remove all of the colons, and then proceed.  For example:

```
NSString *s = @"2011-03-03T06:00:00-06:00";
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZZ"];
NSDate *d = [f dateFromString:s];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

This logs:

```
EmptyFoundation[5088:707] 2011-03-03 12:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the method that I use:

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromISO8601String:(NSString *)dateString{
    if (!dateString) return nil;
    if ([dateString hasSuffix:@"Z"]) {
      dateString = [[dateString substringToIndex:(dateString.length-1)] stringByAppendingString:@"-0000"];
    }
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZ";
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Converting ISO 8601 timestamp into NSDate In Swift:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let inputDate = "2015-06-18T19:00:53-07:00"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ" //iso 8601

let outputDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inputDate)
println(outputDate!) //optional implicitly
```

Or optional explicitly:

```
if let outputDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inputDate) {
     println(outputDate) //no need !
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple supports a [separate format for ISO 8601 format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter)

**Objective C**

```
NSISO8601DateFormatter *formater = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *string = [formater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```