# Why NSDateFormatter can not parse date from ISO 8601 format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting an ISO 8601 timestamp into an NSDate: How does one deal with the UTC time offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc)

I use rails as backend, the default date output is 2008-12-29T00:27:42-08:00

But after my research NSDateFormatter can not support it, except I change date out to 2008-12-29T00:27:42-0800

Here is the code I used to parse ISO 8601 date, but it's not work

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2008-12-29T00:27:42-08:00"]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan It know this link, I just want to get a better solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm looking for a solution that can provide NSDate or NSString for a date formatted as "2008-12-29T00:27:42-08:00". The accepted answer isn't working for me. The problematic part is timezone i.e. "-08:00".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem is with the timezone on the end.

You need to either have it as:  GMT-0X:00  or as -0X00 with no separate between hours and minutes.

The following two combinations work:

Combo 1 - use GMT format (GMT-0X:00) and ZZZZ

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
NSLog(@"DATE FORMAT:%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2008-12-29T00:27:42GMT-08:00"]);
```

Combo 2 - use RFC 822 format (-0X00) and ZZZ

```
dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSLog(@"DATE FORMAT:%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2008-12-29T00:27:42-0800"]);
```

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime 2008-12-29T00:27:42-08:00 is a valid date format. I can change default format from Rails backend, but I think it's not good solution.

Comment: I tried the second solution but there is smth wrong with time zone: "DATE FORMAT:2008-12-29 08:27:42 +0000". "-0800" turned into "+0000"

Comment: this returns nil when used with 2008-12-29T00:27:42Z
and this is also ISO8601 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: In my case I received something like that:

"2015-05-07T16:16:47.054403Z"

And I had to use:

"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSZ"

Comment: swift version: 
`code`
 let date = "2008-12-29T00:27:42-0800"
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ")
            let final = formatter.dateFromString(date) `code`

Comment: to decode iso 8601 formatted date just set the date format to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", the big "S" stands for milliseconds