# How do you convert date time including milliseconds and timezone info to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, datetime-format

I'm trying to convert a string to an NSDate,
however the format always comes out as **nil**

The date I'm trying to convert is:

```
2012-08-16T16:20:52.619000+00:00
```

The date format I'm trying is:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZ"
```

If I change the date to:

```
@"2012-08-16T16:20:52.619000+0000" // removing the : from +00:00
```

it works a treat, however I would

(I have also tried

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ:ZZ" 
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ':'ZZ"
```

but that didn't work either).

Is it even possible to do this without doing string manipulation and removing the final ":"?

Comment: Gee, we haven't had standard question #782 for some time now.  (Use NSDateFormatter, but first you must scrub the string of that last ":" character.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why NSDateFormatter can not parse date from ISO 8601 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925038/why-nsdateformatter-can-not-parse-date-from-iso-8601-format) @HotLicks

Comment: You are both wrong. I have provided an answer below and instead of modifying the date string, make use of "getObjectValue"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a final search around this and found out that you have to use

```
getObjectValue
```

rather than

```
dateFromString
```

In case someone else runs in to this issue, I post my method for converting such strings to NSDate

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"];

    NSDate *theDate = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [dateFormat getObjectValue:&theDate forString:dateString range:nil error:&error];
    [dateFormat release];
    return theDate;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how getObjectValue would work any differently from dateFromString in this case.  In either case it seems like the input string would need to be scrubbed.

Comment: This doesn't change a thing. `dateFromString:` _calls through to_ `getObjectValue:...` The former is just a convenient wrapper for the latter, for when you don't care about the details of possible errors.

Comment: I suggest you try out the code before you mark it down or make such a statement.

Comment: You still didn't test the code: here is more support for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3968411/200341

Comment: I did try it. Did you try mine? They do _exactly the same thing_.

Comment: This is really interesting: I did try your code out and I added the results and code used to pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/S0wHERKc

When I don't use the dateformatlogger it returns nil, however when I use the date format logger it returns the correct date.

It's a shame this is being marked down in case anyone else has this issue, however I have found since then quite a few links to issues of the same nature (you just have to search for "rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone")

Comment: Limit still only SSS (three S), no micro seconds with getObjectValue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using ISO 8601 formatted dates. If you are getting these from a web service, the format changes according to the format. Check this out:

http://boredzo.org/iso8601parser/

This will convert dates according to the format, and even when the format changes slightly.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

the Z has to be in single quotes.

Comment: This does not take into consideration the milliseconds. However it's a case of using getObjectValue rather than dateFromString

Comment: so `.SSSS'Z'` hardly worth the -1