# NSDateFormatter to parse ISO8601 with and without milliseconds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, datetime

Is it possible to have a `NSDateFormatter` parse both an ISO8601 date with and without milliseconds.

I have the following 2 date formats being returned by an API and sometimes they have milliseconds included and sometimes not.

For example I might have `2013-07-23T13:45:02Z` and `2013-07-23T13:45:02.677Z`. For the former setting the `dateFormat` property to `@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"` works fine.

Is there a format I can use to parse the later, optionally parsing the milliseconds if they exist?

Answer (score 8):

For "2013-07-23T13:45:02Z"
Use: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

For "2013-07-23T13:45:02.677Z"
Use: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Check the date format string to see which to use or try one and if it fails try the other.

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)