# Displaying time from Date string

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I have a time string in the following format([`ISO 8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)):

```
 start = "1900-01-01T11:30:00"
 stop = 1900-01-01T21:30:00
```

From the above string I need to display time like this :

```
Starting Time : 11:30a.m
Stopping Time : 09:30p.m
```

For that I had created an NSDate using below code, But I think it displays time in GMT format.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:opening];
stopTime = date;

//Output of above code : Date = 1900-01-01 15:36:40 +0000
```

How can I obtain the Starting and Ending time string from above `ISO 8601` time string? Do I need to depend on String operations rather than using iOS `NSDateformatter`?

Comment: I think this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254575/how-do-i-get-iso-8601-date-in-ios

Comment: @Scha I already referred the post you mentioned. But my question is how can I convert it to a format like this: 09:30p.m ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSString *start = @"1900-01-01T11:30:00";
NSString *stop = @"1900-01-01T21:30:00";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *sDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:start];
NSDate *eDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stop];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
start = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sDate];
stop = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:eDate];

NSLog(@"Starting Time : %@", start);
NSLog(@"Stopping Time : %@", stop);
```

And the outputs will be

```
2014-02-12 10:55:13.931 [950:a0b] Starting Time : 11:30 AM
2014-02-12 10:55:13.932 [950:a0b] Stopping Time : 09:30 PM
```

Comment: I guess it will not work when `24 hour` is off in device setting.

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *iso8601valueStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```