# How do I get the current Date in short format in Swift

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

In the images below you can see the code I wrote and the values of all the variables:

```
class fun getCurrentShortDate() -> String {
    var todaysDate = NSDate()
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    var DateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)

    return DateInFormat
}
```

[Variable values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ZKx.png)

As you can see the current date is found no problem, but when I try to change the NSDate to a string, it just won't do it.

Comment: 1. Dont feel ashamed. Everyone starts somewhere.
2. Paste the code directly into your post rather than posting an image

Comment: Can you do a println(DateInFormat) and prove the string is empty?

Comment: Something is weird.  It should be pretty hard to make that particular piece of code fail.  It may be a debugger issue -- the Xcode debugger`s variable display stuff is pretty flaky, and not to be trusted.

Comment: @Aggressor - That should be `println(DateInFormat)`.

Comment: fixed thanks, (read the wrong name)

Answer (score 64):

**Xcode 11 or later • Swift 5.1 or later**

---

```
extension TimeZone {
    static let gmt = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
}
```

---

```
extension Locale {
    static let ptBR = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let date = DateFormatter()
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    func localizedDescription(date dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium,
                              time timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium,
                              in timeZone: TimeZone = .current,
                              locale: Locale = .current,
                              using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> String {
        Formatter.date.calendar = calendar
        Formatter.date.locale = locale
        Formatter.date.timeZone = timeZone
        Formatter.date.dateStyle = dateStyle
        Formatter.date.timeStyle = timeStyle
        return Formatter.date.string(from: self)
    }
    var localizedDescription: String { localizedDescription() }
}
```

---

```
Date().localizedDescription  // "18 Dec 2021 06:43:50"
Date().localizedDescription(in: .gmt)  // "18 Dec 2021 06:43:50" UTC time
Date().localizedDescription(date: .short, time: .short)  // "18/12/21 03:43"
Date().localizedDescription(date: .full, time: .full)  // "Saturday, 18 December 2021 03:43:50 Brasilia Standard Time"
Date().localizedDescription(date: .full, time: .full, in: .gmt)  // "Saturday, 18 December 2021 06:43:50 Greenwich Mean Time"
Date().localizedDescription(date: .full, time: .full, locale: .ptBR)  // "sábado, 18 de dezembro de 2021 03:43:50 Horário Padrão de Brasília"
```

---

```
extension Date {

    var fullDate: String { localizedDescription(date: .full, time: .none) }
    var longDate: String { localizedDescription(date: .long, time: .none) }
    var mediumDate: String { localizedDescription(date: .medium, time: .none) }
    var shortDate: String { localizedDescription(date: .short, time: .none) }

    var fullTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .none, time: .full) }
    var longTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .none, time: .long) }
    var mediumTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .none, time: .medium) }
    var shortTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .none, time: .short) }

    var fullDateTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .full, time: .full) }
    var longDateTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .long, time: .long) }
    var mediumDateTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .medium, time: .medium) }
    var shortDateTime: String { localizedDescription(date: .short, time: .short) }
}
```

---

```
print(Date().fullDate)  // "Saturday, 18 December 2021\n"
print(Date().shortDate)  // "18/12/21\n"

print(Date().fullTime)  // "03:43:50 Brasilia Standard Time\n"
print(Date().shortTime)  // "03:43\n"

print(Date().fullDateTime)  // "Saturday, 18 December 2021 03:43:50 Brasilia Standard Time\n"
print(Date().shortDateTime)  // "18/12/21 03:43\n"
```

Comment: also can add var shortDateTime: String { return "\(self.shortDate) \(self.shortTime)" }

Comment: This is cool. How bout getting date/time from a specific `UTC Offset`?

Comment: Just pass the desired timezone for the localizedDescription method

Comment: how to add milliseconds?

Comment: There is no `timeStyle` option to add milliseconds but you can set a custom localized `dateFormat` using `DateFormatter`'s method  `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` and pass the milliseconds component  `SSS` if you want: `dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HHmmssSSS")`

Answer (score 26):

**SWIFT 4 or 5**

```
extension Date {

 static func getCurrentDate() -> String {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    }
}
```

**Using**

```
print(Date.getCurrentDate())
```

Comment: many people on stackoverflow forget to give the usage, they only define... great answer!!

Comment: This will create a new date formatter every time you call this method.

Answer (score 17):

**Update for Swift 3.0:**
Create an extension for `Date`

```
extension Date {
    func string(format: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Date().string(format: "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

**Swift 2.2:**
Create an extension for `NSDate`

```
extension NSDate {  
    func dateStringWithFormat(format: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
NSDate().dateStringWithFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: This will create a new DateFormatter every single time you call this method.

Comment: Btw when working with most fixed date formats you should set your locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` otherwise your `DateFormatter` will be affected by the user device locale/settings. `extension Date {
    static let formatter: DateFormatter =  {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
    func string(format: String) -> String {
        Date.formatter.dateFormat = format
        return Date.formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}`

Answer (score 10):

You can create a extension for easily transform a `String` into a `NSDate`.

```
extension NSDate {
    func dateFromString(date: String, format: String) -> NSDate {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

        formatter.locale = locale
        formatter.dateFormat = format

        return formatter.dateFromString(date)!
    }
}
```

Than in your function you can `NSDate().dateFromString("2015-02-04 23:29:28", format:  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` and this should works. Input date don't need to be on the same format of output date.

```
func getCurrentShortDate() -> String {
    var todaysDate = NSDate().dateFromString("2015-02-04 23:29:28", format:  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    var DateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)

    return DateInFormat
}

println(getCurrentShortDate())
```

The output is `04-02-2015`.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

Using the extension created by @doovers and some format strings from this [website](http://nsdateformatter.com), you get the following:

```
extension Date {
    func string(format: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Date().string(format: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy") // Saturday, Oct 21, 2017
Date().string(format: "MM/dd/yyyy")        // 10/21/2017
Date().string(format: "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")  // 10-21-2017 03:31

Date().string(format: "MMM d, h:mm a")     // Oct 21, 3:31 AM
Date().string(format: "MMMM yyyy")         // October 2017
Date().string(format: "MMM d, yyyy")       // Oct 21, 2017

Date().string(format: "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z") // Sat, 21 Oct 2017 03:31:40 +0000
Date().string(format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")   // 2017-10-21T03:31:40+0000
Date().string(format: "dd.MM.yy")                 // 21.10.17
```

You could also pass milliseconds to date object like this:

```
Date(1508577868947).string(format: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy") // Saturday, Oct 21, 2017
```

Comment: This will create a new date formatter every time you call this method.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the way Apple suggests

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
```

or if the pre-defined format of .short, .medium, .long and .full are quite right create the template in a locale

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MM/dd/yyyy")
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

Answer (score 4):

```
 let dateformatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter1.dateFormat = "ccc, d MMM yyy"

    let dateString1 = dateformatter1.string(from: datePicker.date)
    print("Date Selected \(dateString1)")
    labelDate.text = dateString1

    let dateformatter2 = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter2.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let dateString2 = dateformatter2.string(from: datePicker.date)
    print("Date Selected \(dateString2)")


    let dateformatter3 = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter3.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let dateString3 = dateformatter3.string(from: datePicker.date)
    print("Date Selected \(dateString3)")

    let dateformatter4 = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter4.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"
    let dateString4 = dateformatter4.string(from: datePicker.date)
    print("Date Selected \(dateString4)")
```

I referred this article on [Codzify.com](https://www.codzify.com/swiftIOS/date-format-in-swift.php). Really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is easiest way to change date format.

**1. Create one swift class for Date extension.**

```
extension Date {
    func today(format : String = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

2. How to use extension.

   **let date = Date().today(format: "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss")**

   **print(date)**

Comment: This is wrong. `YYYY` is for YearForWeekOfYear. You need to use `yyyy`. Besides that creating a DateFormatter is "expensive". This will create a new date formatter every time you call this method. Second you should always set the date formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the dateFormat when using a fixed date format.

Comment: try this `DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2022, month: 1, day: 1).date!.today()`  // "2021-12-18T03:21:18.422" You are creating a instance method and discarding self. If the date doesn't matter it is only for today declare it as static. The usage would be `Date.today()`

Comment: if you want to keep it as an instance method and change it to `return formatter.string(from: self)` make sure to fix the year otherwise `DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2022, month: 1, day: 1).date!.today()` would result in `"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000"`

Comment: I would also add the timezone to the default dateFormat `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"` and set it to UTC (zero seconds from GMT). Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/2303865)

Comment: you are still using `YYYY` which is wrong. This will result in wrong years when the date is in the first or last week of the year. Again you should use `yyyy`

Comment: @LeoDabus This is just an example. You can customize it and get results as per your requirement.