# Swift dateFormat is returning wrong time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to return a date/time coming from my API. Server is based in Amsterdam.

Swift:

```swift
//load from api
print(date)

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Amsterdam")
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
var updated = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(date)")

//return format
print(updated)
```

Return:

```swift
2020-01-10 00:01:01
Optional(2020-01-09 23:01:01 +0000)
```

I don't know why, but the output is returning GMT I think. To output should be `2020-01-10 00:01:01 +0000` because Amsterdam is GMT+1.

Comment: Everything is fine. `print` displays dates in UTC. `2020-01-10 00:01:01 +0100` and `2020-01-09 23:01:01 +0000` is the same point in time

Comment: @vadian The problem is, when I want to store a date (GMT+1) in my realm database, it will be stored as UTC.

Comment: @Bjorn A date is just a point in time. There is no problem to store all dates using UTC/GMT time. When displaying it to the user you just need to parse your date string back to a Date object and use date formatter to display it properly (localized).

Comment: Basically you just need to create a timestamp (if you are storing it as a String) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-time-zone/28016692#28016692. or get the date time interval since reference date if you can store it as a Double (preferred) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502712/2303865. When displaying your date to the user you should respect its locale and the user device settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - Get local date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404154/swift-get-local-date-and-time)

Answer (score 0):

As vadian explained in the comments it's working as it supposed to.

However, if you want to display a local date instead of UTC, you can use my snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257432/10706839).

If know you will always want just one given time zone just modify the code to add the correct amount of seconds.
(In the case of Amsterdam time it's +3600 seconds to UTC for example.)