# How to use a specific GMT for a function which will be recognised by other time zones

Tags: swift, calendar, timezone, date-formatting, gmt

I imagine there's a simple way to do this, I just haven't figured it out yet.

I want to display a button only between 9am to 12pm AEST (GMT+10).

So for a user in AWST (GMT+8), they will not be able to see the button when it is 11am for them.

I have the specific time I want to use

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatterTime = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterTime.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatterTime.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 36000)
let sydneyTime = dateFormatterTime.string(from: date)
  
print(sydneyTime)
```

I have a function which works for the time zone for each location

```
func CheckTime()->Bool
{
  var timeExist: Bool
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  let startTimeComponent = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour: 9)
  let endTimeComponent   = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour: 12, minute: 01)
    
  let now = Date()
  let startOfToday = calendar.startOfDay(for: now)
  let startTime    = calendar.date(byAdding: startTimeComponent, to: startOfToday)!
  let endTime      = calendar.date(byAdding: endTimeComponent, to: startOfToday)!

  if startTime <= now && now <= endTime
  {
      button.isHidden = false
      timeExist = true
      print("9am-12pm")
      print(sydneyTime)
  }
  else
  {
      button.isHidden = true
      timeExist = false
      print("After 12:01pm")
      print(sydneyTime)
  }
    return timeExist
}
```

How do I use the AEST (sydneyTime) instead of the Gregorian time (Calendar) so the function works only during AEST (GMT+10)?

Comment: If It's not the Gregorian calendar, what calendar do they use in the eastern Australia?

Comment: it is the Gregorian calendar but the time 9am in Western Australia is not the same time as the time 9am in Eastern Australia. If the (Calendar) func is used in Western Australia at 9am it will work as if it is 9am for them but it will actually be 11am in the East.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Calendar method `func dateComponents(in timeZone: TimeZone, from date: Date) -> DateComponents` and get the hour component at the desired timezone. Then you just need to check if it is contained in the desired hour range:

```
let timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 36000)!
let hourInAEST = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: Date()).hour!

if 9..<12 ~= hourInAEST {
    print(true)
} else {
    print(false)
}
```