# Getting Date and Time Swift

Tags: swift, date, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have been looking into retrieving the date and time in Swift and this is the recommended strategy for getting a short, readable Date/Time output:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() 
    formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle

    let convertedDate = formatter.dateFromString(currentDate) //ERROR HERE

  print("\n\(convertedDate)")
```

but this throws an Exception saying that `currentDate` is not a valid parameter to be passed because it is of type `NSDate` instead of `String`

Can you help me understand why this is the case? I have only found similar approaches to this when retrieving Date and Time. Thank you very much, all help is appreciated!

Comment: stringFromDate, not dateFromString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to go from a `NSDate` to a `String`, so use `stringFromDate`:

```
let convertedDate = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
```

Comment: Oh. that makes more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is exactly how you can do it in swift 3 syntax -

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.dateStyle = .short
formatter.timeStyle = .short

let convertedDate = formatter.string(from: currentDate as Date)
```

BR

Answer (score 0):

Leo Dabus wrote a good extension for getting a String from NSDate in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/nsdateformatter-stringfromdatensdate-returns-empty-string/28347285#28347285) by Friso Buurman. Obrigado Leo

Mods please note: *I have borrowed from it and **re-written** it because the original code used the same variable names for the declaration of the `static constants` , `string variables` and `argument parameters` which can be confusing for new coders.*

It's a great extension by Leo and it contains mostly `NSDateFormatter` boiler-plate code you can find in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html).

**Swift 2**

```
extension NSDateFormatter {
convenience init(stringDateFormat: String) {
    self.init()
    self.dateFormat = stringDateFormat
}
}

extension NSDate {
struct Formatter {
    static let newDateFormat = NSDateFormatter(stringDateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy")
}
var myNewDate: String {
    return Formatter.newDateFormat.stringFromDate(self)
}
}
```

Console Output:

```
print(NSDate().myNewDate)  // "05-07-2016\n"
```

**Swift 3**

```
extension DateFormatter {
convenience init(stringDateFormat: String) {
    self.init()
    self.dateFormat = stringDateFormat
}
}

extension Date {
struct Formatter {
    static let newDateFormat = DateFormatter(stringDateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy")
}
var myNewDate: String {
    return Formatter.newDateFormat.string(from: self)
}
}
```

Console Output:

```
print(Date().myNewDate)  // "05-07-2016\n"
```