# Calendar.components cannot be used with an array literal in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdate

I'm attempting to build a class's blueprint in order to display the current date as i.e. "Saturday January 14, 2017" but I'm unable to create an array of calendar components in Swift 3.  Will I need to break them up into separate variables like I've done for the year below and then combine each variable into a string?

Here is what I have so far that won't compile but from reading other's code it has worked in the past:

```
import Foundation
class CurrentCalendarDate {
    var currentDateString: String {
        get{
            let date = Date()

            let calendar = Calendar.current

            //let components = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

            let componetsThatWeWant = calendar.component([.year, .day, .month], from: date)

            let readableDate: String = "Today's date is: \(componetsThatWeWant.day) \(componetsThatWeWant.month), \(componetsThatWeWant.year)"

            return readableDate

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var currentDateString: Int {` returns an Int ??? Doesn't make sense

Comment: You are supposed to use DateFormatter. `formatter.dateStyle = .full`

Comment: You can use this as reference and make it full instead of short. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you may need to use `dateComponents(_:from:)` rather than `component(_:from:)`:

```
let componetsThatWeWant = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .day, .month], from: date)
```

But using `DateFormatter` seems to be a better choice.