# Setup for a date formatter (for example) at initialization time?

Tags: swift

Say you have a date formatter that is global

```
let df:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
```

Ideally it would be good to do the `.dateFormat` setup at the same global initialization time - sort of like this

```
let df:DateFormatter = DateFormatter().dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

But there's no alternative initialization for DateFormatter (there's nothing like this `DateFormatter(withDateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")` )

Really, is there a Swift solution to this?  Is there syntax for a code block outside of any class, which, runs early before anything and in which you can setup things of that nature?

(Note - I am entirely aware of alternative approaches such as singletons, extension, etc: this is a Swift structure question, thanks.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865

Comment: Note that it is preferable to use date and time style (short, medium, long or full) which will be localized to the user instead of forcing a dateFormat if you intend to display it to the user.

Comment: The first link shows exactly what vadian answered but declared as static inside Date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a closure to make your settings

```
let df : DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter 
}()
```

However you are discouraged from using uncapsulated global variables.

Comment: To be absolutely totally clear: that closure would just run the once (I guess, literally when iOS launches the app).  There are no circumstances where it would run again when df is used?  (I just did some quick testing - but I though I'd ask.)  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it runs once.

Comment: A simple clear question with a simple clear answer is so rare on SO!  :)  Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You are free to implement a convenience initializer in an extension, like this:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    convenience init(dateFormat: String) {
       self.init()
       self.dateFormat = dateFormat
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-02-22")
```

Comment: from the question: (Note - I am entirely aware of alternative approaches such as singletons, extension, etc: this is a Swift structure question, thanks.)

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own custom class for that like:

```
class myDateformatter : DateFormatter {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        self.timeZone = timeZone
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: from the question: (Note - I am entirely aware of alternative approaches such as singletons, extension, etc: this is a Swift structure question, thanks.)