# Setting UILabel from UserDefualts

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I have saved a date using UserDefaults and my values are being saved and I trying to present my saved date as a string in my view controller but it comes up blank. Am I implementing it wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

let formatter = DateFormatter()

func savedate(){

    UserDefaults.standard.set(datePicker.date, forKey: keyDate)

}

func loadDate(animation: Bool) {

    guard let loadedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: keyDate) as? Date else { return }

    datePicker.setDate(loadedDate, animated: true)

    print(loadedDate)

    let loadedValue = formatter.string(from: loadedDate)
    timeLabel.text = loadedValue
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    loadDate(animation: true)
 }
@IBAction func saveTimeValue(_ sender: Any) {
saveDate()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't set your date formatter options. As it is it will return an empty string for any date:

Try

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.string(from: Date())  // ""
```

To format your date properly using a localized description you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865).