# Date Formatter - show date only

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how to change the output of the below code.

It returns: Optional(2017-11-09 04:54:51 + 00000

I only want the date value 2017-11-09

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let ots = otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = ots.otsBranch
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row].otsDate)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don’t use  String(describing:). You should unwrap your date value using `if let date = otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row].otsDate`

Comment: And get a date description from your date using date formatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter). All though a default style may suit your needs, you can also put in custom formats using [tr35-31 date format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

First create a date formatter property so you don't continously remake one everytime you dequeue a cell.

```
lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let df = DateFormatter()

    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    // You could also try this, it will output something like: 2017/11/09
    // df.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    return df
}()
```

Then in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` Method

```
// replace the cell.detailTextlabel... line with this
if let date = ots.otsDate {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Wrote all the code out of my head, so my apologies if there are any errors.

Comment: The use of `dateStyle` is better than using `dateFormat` since the result is appropriate for the user's locale.

Comment: @rmaddy True for simple cases. However, designers usually want a specific format, which most of the time has nothing to do with a users locale, unfortunately. From the `DateFormatter.Style` documentation: `Do not use these constants if you want an exact format.` But if the default styles work, by all means, use them for the locale benefits.

Comment: by looking at OP code the property you should access is otsDate not date. `if let date = ots.otsDate {`. Btw I agree with @rmaddy. You shouldn't choose how the user will format a date. You should use dateStyle. The only thing you should determine is if it will be displayed short, medium, long or full. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extension` of `Date`

```
extension Date{
    var dateString: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

In your class

```
let ots = otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row]

if let date = ots.otsDate {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = date.dateString
}
```