# DatePickerView Date isn't the same as the date printed on the console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource

I have the following problem. My code is supposed to trigger a DatePickerView when a button is pressed. (In code it's referred to "deadLineTestButton") and when the user successfully selects a date and a time, the console prints a completely different time.

Here is the code I used

```
  @IBAction func deadlineTestButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var savedDate = ""

    var chosenDate:Date = Date()

    let alert = UIAlertController(style: .actionSheet, title: "Select date")

    alert.addDatePicker(mode: .dateAndTime , date: Date()) { (date) in
        // Do something with the date

        print("Choosing date : \(date)")
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        savedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        chosenDate = date


    }

    let saveDate = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { (action) in

        // Calculte differnece in dates

        // Saved date is the homework's due date

        let currentDate:Date = Date()

        // Diffference from days

        let diffInDays = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: currentDate, to: chosenDate).day

        self.deadLineLabel.text = String(diffInDays!)

        print(savedDate)

        if self.courseTextField.text == "Economia" {

            self.economy.deadline = chosenDate



        } else if self.courseTextField.text == "Matematicas" {

            self.matematicas.deadline = chosenDate



        } else if self.courseTextField.text == "Escritura" {

            self.escritura.deadline = chosenDate

        } else if self.courseTextField.text == "Herramientas"{

            self.herramientas.deadline = chosenDate


        } else if self.courseTextField.text == "Autococimiento" {

            self.autoconocimiento.deadline = chosenDate

        } else if self.courseTextField.text == "Administración" {

            self.administracion.deadline = chosenDate


        }




    }
```

This is what happens when I try to run my code

[image: The time that I choose is at 12:38pm but in the console, it logs as if it were at 17:38:07]

[image: Here it's logging as a different time from when I chose it]

In the first photo, the time that I chose was at 12:38om, but in the console, it logs as if it were 17:38:07

Comment: what you are seeing printed is UTC. if you would like to see the current time some just print its description with locale `date.description(with: .current)`

Comment: But how can I save that date in the local time zone? Since I am also trying to calculate the difference between the current day and the date the user picked, both must be in the same time zone so it can be calculated correctly

Comment: You don’t. If you need to display it localized just use DateFormatter

Comment: And how could I use DateFormatter to achieve that? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-short-format-in-swift/28347285?s=1|24.1396#28347285

Answer (score 1):

The date picker shows local time at your location. Printing the date displays the UTC time in the console. You would appear to be 7 hours from UTC.