# How to first date of month

Tags: swift, nsdate

whenever i use this method it always shows wrong date.

```
func startOfMonth() -> Date {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let currentDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .day, .month], from: self)
    return calendar.date(from: currentDateComponents) ?? Date()
}
```

Output:

> 2018-10-31 18:30:00 +0000

I want:

> 2018-11-1 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: That is the _correct_ date. You need to format it in order to display it in your time zone.

Comment: Whats the purpose of `?? Date()` Just force unwrap the result. `return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self))!`

Comment: @Sweeper The date is correct only because today is the first day of the month. His method shouldn't get the day component from the original date.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to get the first day of the month you should not get the day component from the original date:

```
extension Date {
    var startOfMonth: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self))!
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().startOfMonth.description(with: .current) //  "Thursday, November 1, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM Brasilia Standard Time"
```

Comment: Be specific with output!

Comment: You should not print the date (it shows UTC time). You need to use DateFormatter to display the local time

Comment: Your timezone offset is probably -05:30

Comment: @jaskiratjd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-short-format-in-swift/28347285?s=1|21.5659#28347285

Comment: can you please convert it. @LeoDabus

Comment: You don’t need to convert anything just use the link above to display the resulting date as you wish