# How to get a date from European time-only with DateFormatter in Swift

Tags: swift, date, time, timezone, dateformatter

I try to get a date but I only have a time available.
For now, I don't care about year, month or day. All that matters is the time.

My input is in the form "hh:mm:ss" (i.e. European time format).

The problem is that any time above 12:59:59 does not work !

How can I get dates from times above 12:59:59 ????

My code looks like follows:

```
import UIKit

let str = "17:02:09"

let mydateFormatter = DateFormatter()
mydateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
let timezone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CEST") ?? TimeZone.current
mydateFormatter.timeZone = timezone
mydateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE") as Locale?

let date1 = mydateFormatter.date(from: str)

print(date1?.description ?? "no date available")
```

Output:  **no date available**

If I set the str's hour setting to anything below or equal to 12, then it works.

For example, if I set str = "12:02:09", I get the output: **1999-12-31 23:02:09 +0000**

For example, if I set str = "10:02:09, I get the output: **2000-01-01 09:02:09 +0000**

For example, if I set str = "13:02:09, I get the output: **no date available**

How can I get dates from times above 12:59:59 ????

And ideally, how can I get dates that have a matching time with the input-time ?

Comment: change your date formatter to "HH:mm:ss". hh is for 01-12 hours (usually used for am/pm time) HH is for 24h time 00-23 hours

Comment: When you print the date description  it will always show UTC time

Comment: wow - that simple !! Thank you very much. I did not realise that there is another string-format for hours.

Comment: Ah, and for matching time (i.e. same as input-time) I cannot really use `description` since it is in UTC always. I guess I can use the same DateFormatter I already have for is, such as `print(mydateFormatter.string(from: date1 ?? Date()))`

Comment: Yes. Note that when displaying dates to the user you shouldn't use a custom dateFormat. Just use the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` (short/medium/long/full) so it shows the date respecting the user's locale/settings.

Comment: Btw if you need today's date with the time inputed, you can set the date formatter  `defaultDate` to today's date `Date()`. And if you want to zero out the seconds/milliseconds of the date you can use `mydateFormatter.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())`

Comment: Thank you very much, Leo. This is all very helpful !

Comment: You might be interest in this one also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865