# Date Formatter isn't showing correct day of the month when using format "DD"

Tags: swift, date, time, formatter

I am trying to show today's date as March 26 but it is showing as "March 85" when I use this code.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM DD"
let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong date format. `D` is for "day of year". The correct symbol for "day of month" is lowercased `d` Thats why you are getting `85`instead of `26`.

Another point you should consider is to set your locale fixed to `"en_US_POSIX"` if you don't want your date string to reflect the users settings and locale.

Note that you should use Swift native type `Date` instead of `NSDate`.

If your intent is to display it respecting the user locale and settings you should use date formatter `dateStyle` (short, medium, long or full) [How do I get the current Date in short format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-short-format-in-swift/28347285#28347285)

If you need a localized date format limited to 
month and day only, you can use `DateFormatter` method dateFormat from template:

> `class func dateFormat(fromTemplate tmplate: String, options opts: Int, locale: Locale?) -> String?`

---

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MMMMdd", options: 0, locale: .current)
df.string(from: Date())  // "March 27"
```