# Convert Etc/GMT time into Swift Date() global TIme

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am trying to convert date from apple receipt to swift global date and time. But I am not succeeded,

**Purchased time (device):** 2019-08-30 22:23:44 America/Los_Angeles

**Purchased time (server):** 2019-08-31 05:23:44 Etc/GMT

**Expire time (server):** 2019-08-31 05:28:44 Etc/GMT

When I get date by using `Date()`, it's completely or almost some hour difference than my device & those date&time above. I wanted to compare today `Date()` into expire time.

I used below codes but not success,

```
extension Date {
    static func fromAppleServer(dateString: String) -> Date? {
        let seperated = dateString.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: seperated.last!)
        let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: (seperated.dropLast()).joined(separator: " "))
        return dateObject
    }
    static func localUTC() -> Date {
        let date = Date()
        print("Date before conversion: \(date)")
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Los_Angeles")
        return dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
    }
}
```

---

```
let appleDate = Date.fromAppleServer(dateString: "2019-08-30 22:29:02 America/Los_Angeles") //used  2019-08-31 05:23:44 Etc/GMT too
let localUTC = Date.localUTC()

print("Apple Server: ",appleDate) //Always 2019-08-31 05:29:02 +0000
print("Local UTC: ",localUTC)
```

**Update:**

Tried code:

```
extension Date{

    static func fromAppleServer(dateString: String) -> Date?{

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
        return dateObject
    }

    static func localUTC() -> Date{

        let date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
        let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        return dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
    }
}
```

**Debugging Log:**

```
(lldb) po print date
    ▿ 2019-08-31 05:28:44 +0000
- timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 588922124.0

Fix-it applied, fixed expression was:
print; date
(lldb) po print Date.localUTC()
▿ 2019-09-01 03:07:45 +0000
- timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 589000065.0

Fix-it applied, fixed expression was:
print; Date.localUTC()
(lldb) po print self.expiryDate
▿ Optional<String>
- some : "2019-08-31 05:28:44 Etc/GMT"

Fix-it applied, fixed expression was:
print; self.expiryDate
(lldb) po print Date()
▿ 2019-09-01 03:09:03 +0000
- timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 589000143.939402

Fix-it applied, fixed expression was:
print; Date()
(lldb)
```

Here,

Device date is ~ `8:mm PM, Sat 31 August`.
Purchased date is(5 mins duration):`2019-08-31 05:23:44 Etc/GMT` (For device it's 8:mm PM Sat 31 August) 
Expire date is: `2019-08-31 05:28:44 Etc/GMT`
Swift Date is:~ `2019-09-01 03:09:03`

I thought we can easily compare date once `Etc/GMT` time is converted into Swift `Date()` global time. But I can't convert `2019-08-31 05:28:44 Etc/GMT` to  ~ `2019-09-01 03:09:03`. So, how to convert it? or Any other suggestions welcome.

Note: '~' indicates some seconds or minutes delay because of testing time.

Comment: What is `Etc/GMT`?

Comment: it is probably UTC

Comment: @rmaddy, I don't know what is Etc/GMT. Just got in apple receipt json objects.

Comment: @LeoDabus, okay I will convert local time into UTC

Comment: @LeoDabus, Just wanted to convert `etc/GMT` time to global time like Swift `Date()`.

Comment: @Aishu check my post how to parse all your date strings.

Comment: What is global time? Do you mean local time?

Comment: Swift `Date()` gives same time anywhere in this earth. Sorry, I don't know the name, So I called it global time (thought seen some where). I will add updated code and debugger log in question

Comment: To properly parse your string (convert it to a Date object) you need to interprete the timezone as I suggested in my post

Comment: print will always display the UTC time representation of the date object (zero seconds from GMT same as +0000). If you need to display that date to the user you need to use date formatter (date and time style) to respect the user locale and device settings.

Comment: this might help you understand timezones https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus, Okay thank you! I will try and let you know. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aishu your localUTC() method doesn't make any sense. You don't need to do any time conversion. Date is just a point in time. The actual time description will vary depending of the user location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to manually parse your date string. You can use date format `"VV"` to interprete the timezone identifier associated with your date string:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let customDate: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
let dateString = "2019-08-31 05:23:44 Etc/GMT" // or "2019-08-30 22:23:44 America/Los_Angeles"
if let date = Formatter.customDate.date(from: dateString) {
    print(date)  // "2019-08-31 05:23:44 +0000\n"
    print(date.description(with: .current))  // "Saturday, August 31, 2019 at 2:28:44 AM Brasilia Standard Time\n"
}
```