# Swift - Convert 24hr format into 12hr time format

Tags: swift, xcode, time

Im building an app in Swift that gets data from an API then displays it in a more appealing/user readable format.

The API returns an Int that represents time in a 24hr format that looks like this:

```
2200
```

So, what im looking to do is conversion like this:

```
2100  ->  9:00pm
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this in Swift?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself? Several possible routes here, one is to use DateComponents and DateComponentsFormatter. You could [start here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dates_and_times) with your research

Comment: After parsing  your date string you can use this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347285/2303865 to show your date or just the time reflecting the user’s device locale and settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```swift
let date = Date()//Pass your date here either.
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let time = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a 12h format but would have many issues involved. One of them is the leading zero but there would be more issues besides that.

Comment: Agreed his server should send time in a format by which he can first convert it in a proper date string (which can be understood by Date) then pass in above func to get it done.

Comment: I am taking about setting the date formatter locale to en_US_POSIX to avoid it reflecting the devices locale and settings. You should set its calendar to iso8601 as well

Comment: Note that OP asked how to display it in a more appealing/user readable format. Your answer doesn’t take care of it. The proper way to do what OP asked is to use `DateFormatter`‘s `timeStyle` To display it localized using the user device locale and settings instead of setting a fixed `dateFormat` As shown in your post.

Comment: Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-short-format-in-swift/28347285