# How to print Date&time (localized) in current timezone using SwiftDate framework

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, swiftdate

I'm using SwiftDate framework (see link below)
https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate

I'd like to print the date and time in current region/local/timeZone. I can achieve this by using the below code without using SwiftDate:

```
DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .short)
```

Since, SwiftDate provides a shared date formatter. I'd like to know if the same is possible with SwiftDate.

Comment: You don't need a framework for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-short-format-in-swift/28347285?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.0072#28347285

Comment: I know, and I have already given the code that does it without using a library. I've been reading about SwiftDate and I like it. Therefore, I wanted to know if SwiftDate library had a similar option. I didn't want to rewrite any code if it already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried predrag-samardzic code and it worked. Now that there are two options (to do the same job), one with NSDateFormatter and the other with SwiftDate, I thought of profiling them to see which one is better. Here's the code that I used to profile them:

```
func testNSDateFormatter() {
    for _ in 1...10000 {
        print("\(Date().toLocalizedString())")
    }
}

func testSwiftDate() {
    for _ in 1...10000 {
        print("\(Date().localizedDate.toString(.dateTime(.short)))")
    }
}

extension Date {
    func toLocalizedString(dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .short, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .short) -> String {
        return DateFormatter.localizedString(from: self, dateStyle: dateStyle, timeStyle: timeStyle)
    }

    var localizedDate: DateInRegion {
         return self.in(region: Region(calendar: Calendar.current, zone: Zones.current, locale: Locale.current))
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshot from the profiler.

[image: NSDateFormatter Vs SwiftDate - Time Profile]

The result of profiling:

NSDateFormatter - 773x
SwiftDate - 2674x

NSDateFormatter is approximately 3.45 times faster than SwiftDate. Based on the above, I'd recommend using NSDateFormatter over SwiftDate.

Answer (score 1):

I use an extension to get localized date:

```
import SwiftDate

extension Date {

//you can specify region/timezone/locale to what you want
    var localizedDate: DateInRegion {
        return self.in(region: Region(calendar: Calendar.current, zone: Zones.current, locale: Locale.current))
    }
}
```

Then you use it like this (if you need system localized date, just ommit extension part):

```
let dateString = Date().localizedDate.toString(.custom("dd.MM.yyyy."))
```

Comment: The outputs of DateFormatter.localizedString and your localizedDate do not match. I removed the .custom("dd.MM.yyyy.") format you had specified. Users of different regions use different date separators like ".", "/" etc. Therefore, I'd like the date format to be picked up from the device.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. If you want the same output, you can use:

Date().localizedDate.toString(.dateTime(.short))