# Swift - How to create Sort query as Descending on Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase with Alamofire, AlamofireImage to cache my imageURL data on memory and upload ImageShack.

I stuck creating descending query tried to do and search but I couldn't find possible description for me. Here's my test **ref_post** on Firebase.

**childByAutoId()**

-- userUid

-- imageUrl

-- timestamp (I have created using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim))

*Using **NSDate().formattedISO8601** Is it best way or Can you advice me to handle it basically?

How Can I do descending query in Firbase IOS/Swift. Here's my **viewDidLoad**:

```
let query = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp")

    query.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {
            self.posts = []
            for snap in snapshots {
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    print(postDict)

                    let post = Post(imageUrl: postDict["imageUrl"]! as? String, username: DataService.ds.REF_USERS.authData.uid)

                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.posts = self.posts.reverse()
```

To save `NSDate` instances, I personally use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()` which returns an `NSTimeInterval` (which is a `Double`), which you can then save in Firebase. When reading the data, you can obtain the original `NSDate` with `init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)`.

Comment: @Tim  Should I save the timestamp value in Firebase as Double or String?  I was just wondering how firebase will order the data when querying with `ref.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in`. If timestamp (of type Double) is saved as string in Firebase, how will the snapshot elements be ordered when retrieved, in which order?

Comment: @bibscy I believe I stored the timestamp as an integer, but I don't remember the details. You should probably just try it out!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
self.posts.append(post)
```

use

```
self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
```

This will add the items at the beginning of your list and consequently reverse the ascending order you get from firebase into a descending order.