# Firebase query for the 4 highest integer values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the top 4 scores using a scoring system with the new Firebase queries in Swift.  My database looks like this:

```
gameScores
     $gameType
          $userId: 3
          $userId: 2
          $userId: 4
          $userId: 1
          $userId: 5
          $userId: 8
          $userId: 2
     $gameType
          $userId: 1
```

The integer is the score for that userId.  I want to get the 4 highest scores for a given gametype.  Ties don't really matter, the important part is ordering them then pulling these first 4.  The integer is the score for that userId.  I tried using a query which looks like this:

```
DataService.ds.REF_GAMESCORES.child(self.gameType).queryOrderedByValue().
queryLimitedToFirst(4).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in
```

but when I print the snapshot it puts them in the same order they are in the database. I have been working with the observers for a while but this is my first time working with Firebase queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase queryOrderedByChild() method not giving sorted data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222128/firebase-queryorderedbychild-method-not-giving-sorted-data)

Comment: No it's not duplicate because he's ordering his by a score value but I'm ordering mine by a unique Id.  So if he puts queryOrderedByChild("score") then what do I put?  I don't know the id and they are all different so I can't put them in there.

Comment: You will need to sort the data on the client

Comment: Is it returning the correct 4 just unordered? Or all of them unordered?