# Sort Firebase Data with queryOrdered by date

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to arrange my firebase data by date (unix). I thought `queryOrdered(byChild: "date")` would do the trick. Done a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bswift%5D%5Bfirebase-database%5D%20loop%20children) and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222128/firebase-queryorderedbychild-method-not-giving-sorted-data/39229537#39229537) which makes sense:

> But when you request the .value of the snapshot, the keys+data are converted to a Dictionary. Since a dictionary does not have an extra place to put the information about the order, that information is lost when converting to a dictionary.

Using the same json but modified with unix dates...:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "alovelace" : {
      "name" : "Last Year",
      "date" : 1480550400
    },
    "eclarke" : {
      "name" : "New Year Now",
      "date" : 1483228800
    },
    "ghopper" : {
      "name" : "New Year",
      "date" : 1483228800
    }
  }
}
```

... how to sort when my code is like this:

```
DataService.ds.REF_INCOMES.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        print(snapshot)
        for snap in snapshot {
            if let incomeDict = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] { // What needs to change here?
                let key = snap.key
                let income = Income(incomeId: key, incomeData: incomeDict)
                self.incomes.append(income)
                self.incomes.reverse()
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

The image below, "Last Year" should be last but it's not:

[image]

I have a [ruby mentality](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash) so Im lost with swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're missing here is the `sort` function, Please try the code below and let me know what are the results:

```
DataService.ds.REF_INCOMES.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    guard let usersSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String:NSObject] else{

        return
    }

    let users = usersSnapshot["users"] as! [String:AnyObject]
    let sorted = users.sorted{($0.0.value["date"] as! Double) > ($0.1.value["date"] as! Double)}


    print(sorted) // It should be: New Year Now, New Year, Last Year
})
```

Comment: on line `let users`, I got `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: try `print(usersSnapshot)` before error line and see what does contains

Comment: It return the data.

Comment: I'm loading your JSON in Playground and using the same code above...it works fine...weird. Does the data contains the "users" key when you print it?

Comment: Ok, How to assign `sorted` to my class: `var incomes = [Income]()`? I could with `self.incomes.append(income)`

Comment: what is `Income`?

Comment: Ive sorted it. Took me awhile to figure what's going on Ive: `for snap in sorted {...}` In the curley brackets, my same code applies but I've used your `sorted` as the object to loop on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are observing by `.value`, which essentially ignores the order by. Try to observe by `.childAdded`, which does respect the order by operation.

For more info, read the first "Pro Tip": https://howtofirebase.com/collection-queries-with-firebase-b95a0193745d