# Action button not working within UITable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift3

I have been through [few of these tutorial](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1368&bih=799&q=table+cell+action+button+xcode+8&oq=table+cell+action+button+xcode+8&gs_l=serp.3...1245832.1249830.0.1250270.14.14.0.0.0.0.131.938.13j1.14.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.12.806...33i160k1j35i39k1j0i22i30k1j33i21k1.a5S-0AyJ4uc) and I cant seem to call my function via button click. I have followed this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8IVS_rGHcA) but nothing works.

My `tableView` currently working just great, all Im doing now is adding a button so I could pass data to another view but my button click is not calling its function.

```
//class IncomeFeedCell: UITableViewCell: 

@IBOutlet var weak button: UIButton!
```

**View Contoller:**

```
// class IncomeFeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource:

// viewDidLoad:
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

// cellForRowAt indexPath
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IncomeFeedCell") as! IncomeFeedCell
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.configureCell(income: income)
return cell
```

Now the function to call when tapped:

```
func buttonPressed(){
  print("Tapped")
}
```

Simulator:

[image]

Have I missed something simple?

**Edit:**

Apologies for all who and tried to help and got downvoted because I left out more vital information. All this is inside my `viewDidLoad` in `IncomeFeedVC`:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

DataService.ds.REF_INCOMES.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    /**
     * Sorting the object before looping over
     * Info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416359/sort-firebase-data-with-queryordered-by-date
     */
    guard let incomeSnap = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else{

        return
    }

    let sorted = incomeSnap.sorted{($0.0.value["date"] as! Double) > ($0.1.value["date"] as! Double)}

    for snap in sorted {
        if let incomeDict = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let key = snap.key
            let income = Income(incomeId: key, incomeData: incomeDict)
            self.incomes.append(income)
        }

    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya What is and where, please?

Comment: cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside) this line and func buttonPressed(){
  print("Tapped")
} funcation

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the exact problem? What happens when you tap the button?

Comment: @rmaddy When tapped, nothing prints to console.

Comment: check if cell.button is nil ??? before adding any action to button

Comment: Im confident that this should work. Many tutorials has the same as mine. Im using Swift 3, xcode 8.

Comment: @Hrishikesh If `cell.button` was `nil` there would be crashes trying to use the `nil` reference.

Comment: cell.button is not nil

Comment: Could you please share your cell.configureCell(income: income) function.

Comment: Move the configureCell line before setting the tag / addTarget code (yes, @DheerajD might be right, you might overwrite the event handler there)

Comment: And to be sure, put a breakpoint inside the `buttonPressed` method. Is the breakpoint reached when a button is tapped?

Comment: Why are you not connecting `IBAction` in `IncomeFeedCell` like `IBOutlet` you have connected! And make sure that your button is not covered by any other view !

Comment: cell.button.tag = indexPath.row problem is here . all time you got new tag of your button cell so remove it .

Comment: @rmaddy Did but the issue is that it's not even attempting to call the function.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya. There is always a new tag because it is always a new button... There's no reason to delete that if he references the tag later on.

Comment: but its batter to use outlet instead of tag .

Comment: Set the button's tag to row: this is the easiest way to refer to the index of the data array to access the related object for further use. If you don't want to use tag, you can also get the cell by looping sender's superviews, then use `tableView.indexPathForCell` method to get the indexPath.

Comment: I may have a clue here, would `self.tableView.reloadData()` cause an issue elsewhere in my `class`?

Comment: @Sylar would you like to update your question and show us your code of the IncomeFeedVC class and IncomeFeedCell class?

Comment: Post updated. Nothing else to add.

Answer (score -2):

My ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! TestTableViewCell

    cell.bttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickme(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
func clickme(sender: UIButton) {
    print("cliked")
}


}
```

My UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var bttn: UIButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Its working fine in my case.
Can you remove the "self" in your 
`let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IncomeFeedCell") as! IncomeFeedCell` line.

Comment: How does this explain the problem in the question? Why isn't the `buttonPressed` method being called in the OP's code?

Comment: @maddy I just added a working reference.And OP's code is not working probably of cellForRow function I also suggested what could be wrong in his code.

Comment: Pretty much all the code in your answer is irrelevant to this question apart from one func.

Comment: `self` is removed but still the same. Also, I am reloading the `tableView` in `viewDidLoad`. Would that be an issue?

Comment: @Sylar no, there is no problem you call tableView.reloadData() in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score -4):

your button tapped function should be like this:

```
  func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)
  {

  let buttonTag = sender.tag// you can check tag like this

  }
```

Comment: The `sender` parameter is not needed. Adding this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Someone said the `sender` parameter is not needed, yes, you don't need to provide any parameter to an event handler, but it's a bad programming behaviour. You should always pass in `sender` to any event handler for UIControl even you don't use it.

Comment: @sagar his  func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) method is not calling.

Comment: agreed with  @bubuxu sender should be present is good programming but not mandatory

Comment: That's great, but that doesn't necessarily solve OP's problems.

Answer (score -4):

Can you please try

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(IncomeFeedVC.buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Also below function should be implemented in IncomeFeedVC class

```
func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
  print("Tapped")
}
```

Comment: Same. Nothing is printing. I have the function in `IncomeFeedVC`. Weird one

Comment: @sylar Did you implemented func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) in IncomeFeedVC class?

Comment: @Manoj Having it in this format should not matter if his function is in the IncomeFeedVC as he has said it is. Almost think I should DV this.

Comment: Also, why `AnyObject`? it is a method called by a button, so the sender would always be a button.

Comment: @Benjamin it is good practice which I followed.   https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md

Comment: @Manoj Yes I did.