# Swift NSDateFormatter how to get appropriate formate form DatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uidatepicker

I need to get this format form datePicker `2016-09-30T15:01`.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
```

I use this code below but it return:

```
2016-09-30
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016614/1271826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the `T` in the format.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
```

Any literal text (but not punctuation) in a date format must be enclosed in single quotes to indicate that the text isn't a format specifier.

Comment: yea nice solution