# SwiftDate replacement for toDate function swift 3

Tags: date, swift3, xcode8, isodate

in swift 2.x I used toDate function to get iso date using SwiftDate. Any one knows the right replacement for this:

```
let isoDate = stringDate.toDate(DateFormat.ISO8601Format(.Extended))
```

Looking at the SwiftDate documentations, I've tried something like this:

```
let isoDate = stringDate.date(format:.iso8601)
```

but it complaints about format

**EDIT:**

I changed SwiftDate version from 4.0.7 to 4.0.3 and now iso format exists but throws an error

my date string: `"2016-11-24T03:00:00.000Z"`

```
let isoDate = try! dt.date(format: DateFormat.iso8601(options: .extended)).absoluteDate
```

**error: Type 'ISO8601DateTimeFormatter.Options' has no member 'extended'**

```
let isoDate = try! dt.date(format: DateFormat.iso8601(options: [])).absoluteDate
```

**error: no error but throws**

in swift 2.2 I used exactly the same date format.

Comment: It throws in Swift 3.0 so you need to put it inside a Do Try Catch block

Comment: What is the complaint/error message exactly?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: I ended up with the answer from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [SwiftDate CHANGELOG](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> #### SwiftDate 4.0.5
>
> - #293 Added .withInternetDateTimeExtended as options of ISO8601DateTimeFormatter

And here is the [source file](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Sources/SwiftDate/ISO8601DateTimeFormatter.swift):

```
// The format used for internet date times; it's similar to .withInternetDateTime
// but include milliseconds ('yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ').
public static let withInternetDateTimeExtended = ISO8601DateTimeFormatter.Options(rawValue: 1 << 11)
```

This compiles on the current latest version (SwiftDate 4.0.7):

```
let stringDate = "2016-11-24T03:00:00.000Z"
let options = ISO8601DateTimeFormatter.Options.withInternetDateTimeExtended
let format = DateFormat.iso8601(options: options)
let isoDate = try? stringDate.date(format: format)
```

Comment: unfortunately, there is no extended option: Type 'ISO8601DateTimeFormatter.Options' has no member 'Extended'. I changed withInternetDateTimeExtended to withInternetDateTime but it creates nil instead of date. I think that extended part is the key. Perhaps it is a framework version issue? On which version did you check?

Comment: annnd that's the solution :) I was using 4.0.3 :(