# Swift 3 not showing date as label text

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to show some date value as a label text in swift 3, but getting type conversion error. Here is my code.

```
let dateString = "2016-12-15T22:10:00Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let s = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

lblDate.text = s
```

I am getting this error

> Cannot assign value of type date to type string

Any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. You are trying to assign a Date to a String.
2. You have the wrong format for your string.

This fixes both problems:

```
let dateString = "2016-12-15T22:10:00Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let s = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

lblDate.text = s
```

This changes the string from `2016-12-15T22:10:00Z` to `2016/12/16`.

Comment: No, The format I used here is just a sample, i am getting dates like this 2016-12-15T22:10:00Z which i really need to format

Comment: Then please update your question with your real issue instead of wasting people's time with misleading questions.

Comment: try `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim/28016692#28016692

Comment: @h_a86 I updated my answer to reflect your updated question.