# How can I get current GMT 0 in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, time

I'm looking for a way to display the current **GMT-0** time.

So far, I've been doing it like:

```
    let UTCDate = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: UTCDate)
```

However it returns the current time of the **phone**.

How can I get the current GMT-0 time using Swift 3?

Comment: Requesting current time wouldn't return gmt-0 time for me. I don't understand your point.

Comment: You should change your dateFormat to include the Z (timezone) in your final String otherwise the user or developer would not know it is not local time.

Comment: You should also set your date formatar locale to en_US_POSIX and calendar to iso8601.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/2303865

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Before the last line of your code, insert this line:

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0)
```

Or this line:

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"GMT")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func findGMTDate(dateV: Date) -> Date {
let date = dateV
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") // GMT or "UTC"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

print("dateString: \(dateString)")

if let dateR = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(dateR)
    return dateR
} else {
    print("Date conversion failed")
    return Date()
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't change anything. The date in and the date out are the same (at least to the whole second). It's pointless trying to convert a `Date` from one timezone to another. It's only relevant when you wish to convert a `Date` to a `String` for display to the user or for sending to some API that needs the date in a specific format.