# Convert string to Date/Int/Double using codable

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

I am getting a response from an API but the problem is that the API is sending values back as a string of dates and doubles. I am therefore getting the error "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead." I have structured my struct like this to solve the problem but this seems like a patch. Is there any better way to fix this issue? I feel like apple has thought of this and included something natively to address this.

```
struct SimpleOrder:Codable{ 
    var createdDate:Date! {
        return createdDateString.dateFromISO8601
    }
    var createdDateString:String

    var orderId:String!

    var priceVal:Double!
    var priceString:String{
        didSet {
            priceVal = Double(self.priceString)!
        }
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        //case createdDate
        case createdDateString = "time"

        case orderId = "id"

        case priceVal
        case priceString = "price"
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is relevant but this is how it is being used. I am getting the data as a string and converting it to data which is stored in the `dataFromString` variable

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601 //This is irrelevant though because the date is returned as a string. 

do{
    let beer = try decoder.decode(SimpleOrder.self, from: dataFromString)
    print ("beer is \(beer)")
}catch let error{
    print ("error is \(error)")
}
```

As a result of using codable, I am getting an error when trying to get an empty instance of `SimpleOrder`. Before I was using codable, I had no issues using `SimpleOrder()` without any arguments.

Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SimpleOrder' with no arguments

```
var singlePoint = SimpleOrder()
```

Comment: Don't use didset. Make priceVal a computed property with a getter but without a setter

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `var priceVal: Double { return Double(priceString) ?? 0 }`

Comment: so that is the method that I used for the date. There is no better way to do it? Nothing that is build into Codable so that there doesn't need to be two duplicate properties in the struct (one as a string and the other as a date/double/int).

Comment: Btw no need to repeat case case case. Just use a single one `case createdDateString = "time", orderId = "id",  
priceString = "price"`

Comment: You are not storing any value. It will be computed when needed

Comment: yes I know but I just like the way it looks when there are multiple cases

Comment: Btw you can add those computed properties in an extension to make your structure more readable

Comment: awesome thanks a lot! I am also getting this error: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SimpleOrder' with no arguments` when I do this `var emptyPoint = SimpleOrder()`. Before I started using codable, this was not an issue.

Comment: priceVal shouldn't be a coding key

Comment: if I don't put priceVal in the keys, then it says it doesn't conform to the codable protocol

Comment: It won't complain once you make it a read only computed property as I suggested

Comment: yes, that is why `createdDate ` is commented out above as well

Comment: For the date you can use a custom date formatter to decode it

Comment: `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(Formatter.iso8601)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim/28016692#28016692

Comment: YES. That is what I was looking for I think for the date. I haven't tried it but it looks like it will work. Do you know how I can have an empty property instance of SimpleOrder? like `let tempOrder = SimpleOrder()` I am getting this error: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SimpleOrder' with no arguments`

Comment: I just updated it! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Does this have something to do with `convenience init()` ?

Comment: Why would you need that? and Yes you need to create the initializer and make your properties optionals or give them a default value

Comment: So that I can use that struct like this `var singlePoint = SimpleOrder()` I am not sure if that is what I need.

Comment: Get rid of all this implicitly unwrapped optionals

Comment: I did that but it is still giving the same issue and it says this is what my argument needs to be `SimpleOrder(from: <#T##Decoder#>)`

Comment: Again create an initializer providing default values to the properties or nil

Comment: how do I create an initializer without any arguments?

Comment: sorry, how exactly would I do that? `init(){createdDateString=""}` something like this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
struct SimpleOrder: Codable {
    var created: Date?
    var orderId: String?
    var price: String?
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case created = "time", orderId = "id", price
    }
    init(created: Date? = nil, orderId: String? = nil, price: String? = nil) {
        self.created = created
        self.orderId = orderId
        self.price = price
    }
}

extension SimpleOrder {
    var priceValue: Double? {
        guard let price = price else { return nil }
        return Double(price)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

Decoding the json data returned by the API:

```
let jsonData = Data("""
{
    "time": "2017-12-01T20:41:48.700Z",
    "id": "0001",
    "price": "9.99"
}
""".utf8)
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(Formatter.iso8601)

do {
    let simpleOrder = try decoder.decode(SimpleOrder.self, from: jsonData)
    print(simpleOrder)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Or initialising a new object with no values:

```
var order = SimpleOrder()
```

Comment: In swift 4:
`decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601`

Comment: @jumper that won’t include fractional seconds