# How can I use JSONDecoder / Codable with this date format?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, codable, jsondecoder

I get the following date back from an API.

```
{
  "createdDate": "2019-03-22T15:53:06.663Z"
}
```

I'd like to decode this and store it as a `Date` type.

My `JSONDecoder` is not able to decode this however.

I have tried to extend it with

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let iso8601Full: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

and then using `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)` but this does not work

Comment: What output you getting?

Comment: **What** does not work? Actually `JSONDecoder` is a bit overkill for a dictionary with one key-value pair.

Comment: I'm only including the relevant props, there is a lot more included.

Comment: The date formatter is correct for the given ISO8601 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ISO8601DateFormatter` with formatting options

```
let str = "2019-03-22T15:53:06.663Z"
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withFullTime, .withTimeZone, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = formatter.date(from: str)
```

Comment: or simply `[.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]`. Btw you can't use ISO8601DateFormatter with `dateDecodingStrategy`. You would need to create a custom Date decoding strategy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-time-zone/28016692#28016692