# What is date format for string "2019-06-22T01:11:08.996Z"?

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I have a string form `2019-06-22T01:11:08.996Z` but I can't work out why my date formatter won't convert it to an `NSDate` object. I have tried using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. But I always get nil.

What would be the correct format for form date as above?

Comment: Hint: You are not handling the fractional seconds.

Comment: Even better, use `ISO8601DateFormatter` and don't worry about the format. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-time-zone

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: @AtalayAsa That's the wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code to get the date:

```
    let dateStr = "2019-06-22T01:11:08.996Z"
    let date = dateFrom(dateString: dateStr, withDateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", andLocale: "en_US_POSIX")
    print(date)
```

--

```
func dateFrom(dateString: String, withDateFormat dateFormat: String, andLocale locale: String) -> Date? {
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.locale = Locale(identifier: locale)
    dateformatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    return dateformatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

Comment: 1. Wrong date format. 2. Wrong locale. 3. Don't use `NSLocale`, use `Locale`. 4. Don't force-unwrap the result. The return type should be `Date?`, not `Date!`.

Comment: Still need to fix the locale. You need `en_US_POSIX`.