# How to format this date string format "2018-03-30T14:36:10.093" into Date in Swift

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I'm trying to get the Date object for this string format "2018-03-30T14:36:10.093" in Swift, but I don't get it. It is not ISO8601 because of that point after the number 10.

Any solutions?

Comment: Yes it is. The decimal fraction is legal and is part of the specification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/2303865

Answer (score -3):

I got it. It's about to trim the string from the point after the 10 number and give the date formatter the following format:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: If you trim your string you will be discarding the date fractional seconds.

Comment: No, now you’ve thrown away part of the number, resulting in a different date.

Comment: `let s = "2018-03-30T14:36:10.093"; let f = ISO8601DateFormatter(); f.formatOptions = .withFractionalSeconds; let d = f.date(from: s)`

Comment: @matt this is wrong. First the string should end with the timezone `Z`. Second you need to pass a set `[.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]` or simply `f.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh well. The point is your answer has this covered and I've pointed to it appropriately. I was just trying to show that the OP's string is not vitiated by the decimal fraction as the OP claimed.