# What is the date formater for this string?

Tags: swift, date-format

I am working in Swift language. I don't know the date format for this `2020-07-23T00:17:06.000Z`.

I want to convert `Date` to `String` by following that format & vice versa.

How can I do? Thanks in advance...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-time-zone/28016692#28016692

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is [iso8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)

```
let string = "2020-07-23T00:17:06.000Z"
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
```

Comment: maybe I am lucky. thanks for pointing out