# Date Format in Swift 5

Tags: swift, dateformatter

When I send the post request to api, date is registered as 01-01-0001. I think I need to send format like this "2020-09-19T21:01:48.5558219+03:00" How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a date time stamp and format as ISO 8601, RFC 3339, UTC time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ISO8601DateFormatter` object.