# Unable to convert string to date, string contains dot with 6 character

Tags: swift, date, swift5

I stuck to convert string to date, my date string is
"2021-03-25T06:35:36.372245"
Unable to convert it into date formate. I used the code but unable to convert, i got nil.
My code is

```
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ZZZZZZ" ( also tried SSSSSS)
    let dte = dateFormatter.date(from: dateTime)
```

but unable to parse it. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Try this formate "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Comment: Doesn't seem to be TimeZone to me, so not the "Z", but more seconds, to the "S". Try `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"` If you print `dateFormatter.string(from: Date())`, you'll see that the `T` is breaking, you need to escape it.

Comment: thanks @Larme its working i used the same but not used T with ''('T'), T is the separator so their is need to write T with '' .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-can-i-parse-create-a-date-time-stamp-formatted-with-fractional-seconds-utc

Answer (score 1):

You forget `''` arround T

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
```

Comment: After changing the formate, time get changed "Optional(2021-03-25 01:05:36 +0000)" how to match this

Comment: You re in 5.5 GMT , As of time zone see edit

Comment: thanks , Its working but if my server change location, then it will not work according to that, So can we change string to date without changing the zone

Comment: no we can't as it takes the default zone if you don't set it

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let dte = dateFormatter.date(from: dateTime)
```

Comment: This is wrong. You should never escape the `Z`. Btw there is no timezone in the date string so you should remove it and set the dateFormatter's timezone to zero seconds from GMT

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, thanks for pointing