# Date string to Swift Date

Tags: swift, datetime

I've tried using a `DateFormatter()` to format a string (from C# `DateTime`) into a Swift `Date()`. However, I keep getting `nil`.

Here is the code I've been playing around with:

```
let dateAndTimeString = "2021-08-24T10:16:06.647" //Copied from a C# API

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" //Also trying without this dateFormat returns nil

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAndTimeString) //Returns nil
```

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dateFormat` you used is not matched with the given date string. The correct `dateFormat` should be below

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thanks! 

Comment: This would still have some issues and it might fail if the user's device 12-24 hour settings is set to 12h. Check the correct approach at the duplicated SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/2303865)