# Firebase timestamp decode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following object:

```
struct CustomModel: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var creationTime: Timestamp? <-----
    var providerData: [ProviderData]?
    var uid: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case creationTime
        case providerData
        case uid
    }
}
```

Decoding it:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(CustomModel.self, from: jsonData)
```

I'm getting the following error for trying to Decode the Firebase Timestamp:

> could not parse json keyNotFound(TimestampKeys(stringValue: "seconds", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "creationTime", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key TimestampKeys(stringValue: "seconds", intValue: nil) ("seconds").", underlyingError: nil))

I'm using Firebase Functions to interact with Firebase, and with that I need to decode this object, the problem is that I have no idea how to handle the creationTime firebase timestamp. I don't wanna use CodableFirestore library since its outdated.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the `Timestamp` model struct to the question?

Comment: Show the lines where you read the snapshot document or equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Timestamp` is not a supported type of the `Codable` protocol. Remember that `Timestamp` is a Firestore custom type, not a native Swift type. `Date`, however, is a native Swift type and one that is supported by `Codable`, and it's easily convertible between `Timestamp`.

```
let date = timestamp.dateValue()
let timestanmp = Timestamp(date: date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create the model:

```
struct CustomModel: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var creationTime: Date?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case creationTime
    }
}
```

And the init for the model:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
  self.type = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
  let dateString = try values.decode(String, forKey: .createdAt)
  self.creationTime = dateString.iso8601withFractionalSeconds
}
```

See the formatting String to date by calling 'iso8601withFractionalSeconds' here [How can I parse / create a date time stamp formatted with fractional seconds UTC timezone (ISO 8601, RFC 3339) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-can-i-parse-create-a-date-time-stamp-formatted-with-fractional-seconds-utc)

All other values you can also decode by following Swift decoding requirements.