# Convert Date to required format

Tags: ios, swift

I need to convert `"2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"` to `"dd MMM yyy"` format.
I have tried doing it as suggested in a stackoverflow answer but it returns `nil`

```
func convertDate(date:String)-> String{
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyy"
    if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: String(date)) {
        let convertedDate = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
        return convertedDate
    } else {
        print("There was an error decoding the string")
    }
    return "nil"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fractional seconds are missing in the date format string. It's `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

And you are not using the `date` parameter. To avoid confusion with the local variable `date` rename it.

And you don't need two date formatters and it's highly recommended to set the `Locale` to a fixed value

```
func convertDate(dateString: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyy"
       return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
       print("There was an error decoding the string")
       return ""
    }
   
}
```

Comment: You always forget to set the calendar. This would "fail" if the user device 's calendar is set to a different calendar like Buddhist. The year would be more than 500 years offset. Btw `dd MMM yyyy`

Answer (score -1):

got the answer

```
func convertDate(date:String)-> String{
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"
    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyy"
    if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: String(date)) {
       let convertedDate = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
       return convertedDate
    } else {
       print("There was an error decoding the string")
    }
   return "nil"
}
 print(convertDate(date: "2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"))
```

Comment: This has numerous issues. Do you want me to enumerate them?

Comment: yes that would be very helpful

Comment: 1) `s` is for seconds. What you need is `S` for fractional seconds

Comment: 2) When working with fixed date format you should always set the locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`. Please take some time and read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html). Most importantly **you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences.**

Comment: 3) You should always set the formatter'
s calendar to iso8601. If you don't set a calendar this would "fail" if the user device 's calendar is set to a different calendar like Buddhist. The year would be more than 500 years offset.

Comment: 4) you should use `yyyy` instead of `yyy`

Comment: 5) Last but not least. This would create a new (two) date formatters every time you call this method. You should  create a static date formatter for parsing your dates. Note that there is an `ISO8601DateFormatter`
 which is exactly for this purpose (encoding/decoding iso8601 date strings)

Comment: Btw take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/2303865)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).