# When parsing a date from a string, how can I stop it from being converted to local time?

Tags: swift

When I convert any sort of timestamp to a date, whether it be UTC or with another offset, it converts it to my local time. How can I stop it from doing that?

As an example, the following code prints out  `2022-05-24 09:40:11 +0000` but it should show up as `2022-05-24 01:40:11 +0000`. I do not want the equivalent time in my own time zone that it is returning

```
let dateStr = "2022-05-024T01:40:11.126-08:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
let parsedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
print(parsedDate)
```

Comment: `Date` is just a container for the amount of time which has passed since some anchor point (ie milliseconds since the Unix Epoch), it doesn't "convert" the value, what it does do is, when you "print" make use of the platforms locale to present a "human readable" presentation of the time it represents

Comment: `parsedDate` will contain the correctly converted date, you just testing it wrong with `print`. Instead do this: `print(parsedDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)` and see that this is the right date (for example via this site: https://www.epochconverter.com/). Also `2022-05-024` is not a valid date.

Comment: You date is being correctly parsed but there are other issues with your implementation

Comment: to check if your date was parsed correctly you need also to use your date formatter to convert the date back to string `print(dateFormatter.string(from: parsedDate))`

Comment: Btw you should use `let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()` and insert `withFractionalSeconds` to its formatOptions `dateFormatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)` or check this post how to properly deal with iso8601 date format [How can I parse / create a date time stamp formatted with fractional seconds UTC timezone (ISO 8601, RFC 3339) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/2303865)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is just a container for the amount of time which has passed since some anchor point (ie milliseconds since the Unix Epoch), it doesn't "convert" the value, what it does do is, when you use "print", it make use of the platforms locale/timezone to present a "human readable" presentation of the time it represents

For example...

```
let dateStr = "2022-05-024T01:40:11.126-08:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
print(date)
```

prints `2022-05-24 09:40:11 +0000`

But, if I change the formatter's timezone, for example...

```
let utcFormatter = DateFormatter()
utcFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
utcFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let utcDate = utcFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
print(utcDate)
```

it still prints `2022-05-24 09:40:11 +0000`

Okay, it's printing in UTC anyway, so lets trying a different timezone:

```
let auFormatter = DateFormatter()
auFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
auFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "AEST")
let auDate = auFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
print(auDate)
```

it still prints `2022-05-24 09:40:11 +0000`

If we read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779759-description) it actually says *"The representation is useful for debugging only."*

If you want the presentation done differently, use a different formatter, for example...

```
let dateStr = "2022-05-024T01:40:11.126-08:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
print(date)

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -(8 * 60 * 60))
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "AEST")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

Which prints...

```
2022-05-24 09:40:11 +0000        // print(date)
2022-05-24T09:40:11.126Z         // UTC
2022-05-24T01:40:11.126-08:00    // -8
2022-05-24T19:40:11.126+10:00    // AEST
```

*(obviously you could also configure the `Locale` for different representations)*

They all represent the same date/time value, just at different time zones

You could also check the different date values using `Date#timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` or `Date#timeIntervalSince1970`, for example...

```
let dateStr = "2022-05-024T01:40:11.126-08:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!.timeIntervalSince1970)

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!.timeIntervalSince1970)

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -(8 * 60 * 60))
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!.timeIntervalSince1970)

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "AEST")
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!.timeIntervalSince1970)
```

which prints...

```
1653385211.126
1653385211.126
1653385211.126
1653385211.126
```

And as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779963-timeintervalsince1970) state, *"The interval between the date value and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970."*

In this case, the formatter timezone has not effect on the parsing, only the presentation (the `locale` can fix parsing issues, but that's another topic)