# Swift ISO8601DateFormatter not writing UTC offset when printing GMT date

Tags: swift, timezone-offset, dateformatter

I am trying to print a date and time, I would like the `String` representation to include the UTC offset.
This seems to work for date and times which are in the BST time zone, however when the date and time is in the GMT time zone the `String` doesn't contain the offset, but the "Z".

The code I am using is:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone). // timeZone = "Europe/London"
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withTimeZone]
formatter.string(from: date). // date is a Date object
```

The output looks like:
`2023-10-16T10:00:00+01:00` for a BST date and time.
`2023-11-01T20:42:59Z` for a GMT date and time

Is there a way to have the GMT date and time look like `2023-11-01T20:42:59+00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you would need a custom `dateFormat`. `ISO8601DateFormatter` doesnt give that option AFAIK.

If you would like to have `timeZone` without Z you would need to pass `xxxxx` to the date formatter's dateFormat.

[image]

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxxx"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
Formatter.iso8601.string(from: .now)  // "2023-11-01T22:02:10+00:00"
```

---

```
extension TimeZone {
    static let london: TimeZone = .init(identifier: "Europe/London")!
}
```

---

```
if let date = Formatter.iso8601.date(from: "2023-10-16T10:00:00+01:00") {
    Formatter.iso8601.timeZone = .london
    Formatter.iso8601.string(from: date)  // "2023-10-16T10:00:00+01:00"
}
```

---

For more detailed post about iso8601 check this [How can I parse / create a date time stamp formatted with fractional seconds UTC timezone (ISO 8601, RFC 3339) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-can-i-parse-create-a-date-time-stamp-formatted-with-fractional-seconds-utc/28016692#28016692)

Comment: Interesting, as I am not interested in fractional seconds, that was further down my reading list.

Comment: I have accepted this as the correct answer, however as indicated by Joakim below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77405741/4187837) there is probably no issue in the first place.

Comment: @Gavin the question is “Is there a way to have the GMT date and time look like 2023-11-01T20:42:59+00:00?” I never said it was an issue. ISO8601 allows you to choose the utc timeZone to be represented with or without Z as you can see at the image above. With Z is definitely the most used option probably because it’s short format. Note that changing the ISO8601DateFormatter timeZone is an expensive operation and should be avoided.

Comment: FWIW - though most implementations of date/time parsers will treat `Z` and `+00:00` identically, there is a semantic difference according to ISO 8601.  The difference is that `Z` means UTC, whereas `+00:00` means that there is zero offset between UTC and the value given.  Thus, `+00:00` is more appropriate than `Z` for local time zones like `Atlantic/Reykjavik`, `Africa/Monrovia`, or the non-DST portion of `Europe/London`.

Comment: I really prefer not to store any time zone info at the date string. Most people doesn’t know how to deal with it. Even the Z people don’t know what it means and I’ve seen a lot of people escaping the Z and discarding the time zone info (parsing it as local time)