# NSDateFormatter for datetime

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a string which is coming from an API that I need to convert into a `NSDate` but I'm uncertain which dateFormat to use for `NSDateFormatter`.

```
let openedAt = "2015-06-30T12:34:00.000-04:00" // coming from API

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd..." // not sure what format to use here

if let date = formatter.dateFromString(openedAt) {
    println(date)
} else {
    println("NOPE!")
}
```

Comment: Look at this topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254575/how-do-i-get-iso-8601-date-in-ios

Comment: http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
```

The [Date Format Patterns guide](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) suggests that "S" is the format specifier for fractions of seconds.

Comment: Isn't that missing the UTC time offset?

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It is wrong. It's missing the needed format for the timezone.

Comment: No, you need to put back the fractional seconds.

Comment: now my console output is `teh output==2015-06-30 16:34:00 +0000`, this is fine bro

Comment: @rmaddy -- check once I got the output in console correctly if you need tell me I modify my answer

Comment: @rmaddy -- I am waiting for your valuable feed back

Comment: @rmaddy - tanx a lot my brother, actually yesterday I added my answer initially is correct after the some time I changed my answer , now I modified my answer in old style