# Use SwiftyJSON to deserialize NSDate

Tags: json, swift, nsdate, swifty-json

What is the best way to deserialize a [JSON date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) into an `NSDate` instance using SwiftyJSON?

Is it to just use `stringValue` with `NSDateFormatter` or is there a built in date API method with SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like NSDate support isn't built in to SwiftyJSON, but you can extend the JSON class with your own convenience accessors.

The following code is adapted from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/421).

```
extension JSON {
    public var date: NSDate? {
        get {
            if let str = self.string {
                return JSON.jsonDateFormatter.dateFromString(str)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    private static let jsonDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
        let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
        fmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        return fmt
    }()
}
```

Example:

```
let j = JSON(data: "{\"abc\":\"2016-04-23T02:02:16.797Z\"}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

print(j["abc"].date)  // prints Optional(2016-04-23 02:02:16 +0000)
```

You might need to tweak the date formatter for your own data; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254575/how-do-i-get-iso-8601-date-in-ios) for more examples. Also see [this question about date formatting in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10286204/23649).

Comment: Thanks, this looks great.  Yes I have to tweak my date formatting.  It's not working now with an example date of `2016-04-24T16:47:58.319+0000`.   Not sure why this doesn't jive with the `NSDateFormatter` format that you mention in the answer.

Comment: Because the dateFormat I used doesn't accept time zone information. Look at the other questions I linked; I think the answers include an example that does.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3** Version

```
extension JSON {
    public var date: Date? {
        get {
            if let str = self.string {
                return JSON.jsonDateFormatter.date(from: str)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    private static let jsonDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```