# How to Convert duration form youtube api in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new swift developer i don't know how to convert duration from youtube api to normal time format?

Comment: Here is your answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16254918/2713079

Comment: This answer are convert from normal date to iOS
But i want to convert from iOS to normal?

Comment: Can you give an example of the date in the format that it is provided from youtube api? and an example of what format you'd like to convert it to?

Comment: Example "PT3H2M31S" want convert to hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 10):

A simpler implementation considering return value in hh:mm:ss format only.

```
extension String {

    func getYoutubeFormattedDuration() -> String {

        let formattedDuration = self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("PT", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("H", withString: ":").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("M", withString: ":").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("S", withString: "")

        let components = formattedDuration.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        var duration = ""
        for component in components {
            duration = duration.characters.count > 0 ? duration + ":" : duration
            if component.characters.count < 2 {
                duration += "0" + component
                continue
            }
            duration += component
        }

        return duration

    }

}
```

**Swift 3

```
  func getYoutubeFormattedDuration() -> String {

    let formattedDuration = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "PT", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "H", with:":").replacingOccurrences(of: "M", with: ":").replacingOccurrences(of: "S", with: "")

    let components = formattedDuration.components(separatedBy: ":")
    var duration = ""
    for component in components {
        duration = duration.characters.count > 0 ? duration + ":" : duration
        if component.characters.count < 2 {
            duration += "0" + component
            continue
        }
        duration += component
    }

    return duration

}
```

Sample Results:

```
"PT3H2M31S".getYoutubeFormattedDuration() //returns "03:02:31"
"PT2M31S".getYoutubeFormattedDuration() //returns "02:31"
"PT31S".getYoutubeFormattedDuration() //returns "31"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using String Extension:

```
extension String{

    func formatDurationsFromYoutubeAPItoNormalTime (targetString : String) ->String{

        var timeDuration : NSString!
        let string: NSString = targetString

        if string.rangeOfString("H").location == NSNotFound && string.rangeOfString("M").location == NSNotFound{

            if string.rangeOfString("S").location == NSNotFound {
                timeDuration = NSString(format: "00:00")
            } else {
                var secs: NSString = targetString
                secs = secs.substringFromIndex(secs.rangeOfString("PT").location + "PT".characters.count)
                secs = secs.substringToIndex(secs.rangeOfString("S").location)

                timeDuration = NSString(format: "00:%02d", secs.integerValue)
            }
        }
        else if string.rangeOfString("H").location == NSNotFound {
            var mins: NSString = targetString
            mins = mins.substringFromIndex(mins.rangeOfString("PT").location + "PT".characters.count)
            mins = mins.substringToIndex(mins.rangeOfString("M").location)

            if string.rangeOfString("S").location == NSNotFound {
                timeDuration = NSString(format: "%02d:00", mins.integerValue)
            } else {
                var secs: NSString = targetString
                secs = secs.substringFromIndex(secs.rangeOfString("M").location + "M".characters.count)
                secs = secs.substringToIndex(secs.rangeOfString("S").location)

                timeDuration = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", mins.integerValue, secs.integerValue)
            }
        } else {
            var hours: NSString = targetString
            hours = hours.substringFromIndex(hours.rangeOfString("PT").location + "PT".characters.count)
            hours = hours.substringToIndex(hours.rangeOfString("H").location)

            if string.rangeOfString("M").location == NSNotFound && string.rangeOfString("S").location == NSNotFound {
                timeDuration = NSString(format: "%02d:00:00", hours.integerValue)
            } else if string.rangeOfString("M").location == NSNotFound {
                var secs: NSString = targetString
                secs = secs.substringFromIndex(secs.rangeOfString("H").location + "H".characters.count)
                secs = secs.substringToIndex(secs.rangeOfString("S").location)

                timeDuration = NSString(format: "%02d:00:%02d", hours.integerValue, secs.integerValue)
            } else if string.rangeOfString("S").location == NSNotFound {
                var mins: NSString = targetString
                mins = mins.substringFromIndex(mins.rangeOfString("H").location + "H".characters.count)
                mins = mins.substringToIndex(mins.rangeOfString("M").location)

                timeDuration = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d:00", hours.integerValue, mins.integerValue)
            } else {
                var secs: NSString = targetString
                secs = secs.substringFromIndex(secs.rangeOfString("M").location + "M".characters.count)
                secs = secs.substringToIndex(secs.rangeOfString("S").location)
                var mins: NSString = targetString
                mins = mins.substringFromIndex(mins.rangeOfString("H").location + "H".characters.count)
                mins = mins.substringToIndex(mins.rangeOfString("M").location)

                timeDuration = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours.integerValue, mins.integerValue, secs.integerValue)
            }
        }
        return timeDuration as String
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

let youtubeVideoDurationString = "PT15M51S"   

let resultString = youtubeVideoDurationString.formatDurationsFromYoutubeAPItoNormalTime(youtubeVideoDurationString)
    print(resultString)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Convert Hour:Minute:Second format** :-

Using String Extension:

```
extension String{

func parseVideoDurationOfYoutubeAPI(videoDuration: String?) -> String {

var videoDurationString = videoDuration! as NSString

var hours: Int = 0
var minutes: Int = 0
var seconds: Int = 0
let timeRange = videoDurationString.rangeOfString("T")

videoDurationString = videoDurationString.substringFromIndex(timeRange.location)
while videoDurationString.length > 1 {

    videoDurationString = videoDurationString.substringFromIndex(1)

    let scanner = NSScanner(string: videoDurationString as String) as NSScanner
    var part: NSString?

    scanner.scanCharactersFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet(), intoString: &part)

    let partRange: NSRange = videoDurationString.rangeOfString(part! as String)

    videoDurationString = videoDurationString.substringFromIndex(partRange.location + partRange.length)
    let timeUnit: String = videoDurationString.substringToIndex(1)


    if (timeUnit == "H") {
        hours = Int(part as! String)!
    }
    else if (timeUnit == "M") {
        minutes = Int(part as! String)!
    }
    else if (timeUnit == "S") {
        seconds   = Int(part! as String)!
    }
    else{
    }

}
return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

}
}

Usage:
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
    let youtubeVideoDurationString = "PT15M51S"

    let result_Hour_Minute_Second = youtubeVideoDurationString.parseVideoDurationOfYoutubeAPI("PT15M51S") as String

    print("result_Hour_Minute_Second: \(result_Hour_Minute_Second)")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5

```
extension String {

func getYoutubeFormattedDuration() -> String {

    let formattedDuration = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "PT", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "H", with:":").replacingOccurrences(of: "M", with: ":").replacingOccurrences(of: "S", with: "")

    let components = formattedDuration.components(separatedBy: ":")
    var duration = ""
    for component in components {
        duration = duration.count > 0 ? duration + ":" : duration
        if component.count < 2 {
            duration += "0" + component
            continue
        }
        duration += component
    }

    return duration

}

}
```

Usage:

```
let youtubeVideoDurationString = "PT2M24S"
youtubeVideoDurationString.getYoutubeFormattedDuration() //returns 02:24
```