# Swift - ISO 8601 - Youtube API conversion of timestamp to seconds

Tags: swift, youtube, youtube-data-api, iso8601

I've seen plenty of conversions of the ISO 8601 timestamp in other languages but not come across one for Swift.

I'm looking to convert the typical response from the Youtube API:

```
let timestamp = "PT3M53S"
```

To a total number of seconds....

```
seconds: Int = 233
```

Any clues on how to do this, I am torn whether to split the expression up, looking for the number between "M" and "S" to equate to seconds.

Please also consider the expression could include Hours e.g.

```
let timestamp = "PT1H3M53S"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert duration form youtube api in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048139/how-to-convert-duration-form-youtube-api-in-swift)

Comment: Also some Swift code here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1146416