# Convert ISO 8601 to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, formatting, nsdate, nsdateformatter, iso

I have a timestamp coming from server that looks like this:

```
2013-04-18T08:49:58.157+0000
```

I've tried removing the colons, I've tried all of these:

[Converting an ISO 8601 timestamp into an NSDate: How does one deal with the UTC time offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc)

[Why NSDateFormatter can not parse date from ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925038/why-nsdateformatter-can-not-parse-date-from-iso-8601-format)

Here is where I am at:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateUsingStringFromAPI:(NSString *)dateString {


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    //@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" - doesn't work
    //@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ" - doesn't work
    //@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss" - doesn't work 

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

    // NSDateFormatter does not like ISO 8601 so strip the milliseconds and timezone
    dateString = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length]-5)];

    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

One of my biggest questions is, is the date format I have above really ISO 8601? All the examples I have seen from people the formats of each are slightly different. Some have `...157-0000`, others don't have anything at the end.

Comment: You need `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ`.

Comment: No dice, I even tried removing the line to removes the last 5 characters.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo - it should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. Don't trim the string and don't set the timezone.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This works for me:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-04-18T08:49:58.157+0000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
// Always use this locale when parsing fixed format date strings
NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:posix];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
```

Comment: Yes, it may work without the locale but under certain cases (various user settings) it will not. To ensure your code will always work, set the locale to the special posix locale.

Comment: It should be said that if you actually want it in timestamp format you want to change the NSLog statement at the end to the following: NSLog(@"date = %f", [date timeIntervalSince1970]);

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I've thrown away my old POSIX strptime() code in disgust now!

Comment: Also note that allocating NSDateFormatters will affect performance if you're calling this a lot (e.g. churning through chart data points), so you'll want to only do the allocation once.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. This solution will not parse a date such as "2013-01-28", which (according to Wikipedia), is a valid ISO 8601 date. I know there are more or less complex solutions on the web, but is there a way to set a plain NSDateFormatter in such a way that it will parse any legal ISO 8601 date?

Comment: Also, I tried to set the `NSDateFormatter`'s calendar to the `NSCalendar` with identifier `NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601`. This doesn't seem to make a difference. Does anybody know what is this `NSCalendar` good for? I could not find any useful information about it

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys This question really isn't about every possible ISO 8601 date format but just one of them. You would need to try each individual format to see which returns a non-nil `NSDate`. You should open your own question if you need help with that.

Answer (score 19):

There is New API from Apple! `NSISO8601DateFormatter`

```
NSString *dateSTR = @"2005-06-27T21:00:00Z";
NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateSTR];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Answer (score 2):

I also have the native API, which is way cleaner... This is the implementation I got in my DateTimeManager class:

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateFromISO8601:(NSString *)strDate{

    NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString: strDate];
    return date;
}
```

Just copy and paste the method, it would do the trick. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

The perfect and best solution that worked for me is:

```
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter();
isoFormatter.formatOptions = [ISO8601DateFormatter.Options.withColonSeparatorInTime,
                                      ISO8601DateFormatter.Options.withFractionalSeconds,
                                      ISO8601DateFormatter.Options.withFullDate,
                                      ISO8601DateFormatter.Options.withFullTime,
                                      ISO8601DateFormatter.Options.withTimeZone]
let date = isoFormatter.date(from: dateStr);
```

For further more detail, you can refer to apple's official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter