# Getting NSDate from time string with UTC format

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get a `NSDate` object from a UTC time string. The example of the time string is this:

```
2016-07-29T11:43:55+02:00
```

I am using`NSDateFormatter` and set the formate as: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

However this gives me the take with incorrect time zone. So the above date will be:    2016-07-29T09:43:55+00:00

How do I keep the time zone aspect as well?

I did try adding a `'Z'` to the end of the formatter but that just returns a nil date.

Comment: That's correct. 9 is two hours behind local time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ISO 8601 to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558859/convert-iso-8601-to-nsdate)

Comment: Your date format is correct and the date string is parsing correctly, so are you asking how you detect what GMT offset the incoming date string had?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 NSDateFormatter *userFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [userFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
 NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
 [userFormatter setLocale:posix];
 NSString *dateConverted = [userFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];
```

Comment: That won't work (missing `'T'` in formatter) and it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that help. Solved the issue. The time on my iOS Simulator was correct. However when I called `[NSDate date];` it show'd me a time two hours before local time. Hence the 'errors' I was seeing in the formatting of NSDate.

Comment: Showed you where?  `NSLog()` by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, NSLog. Is there a reason why the iOS Simulator shows correct time but NSLog doesn't?

Comment: Seriously; this is probably the single most asked questions on stackoverflow and I don't see any reason why an iOS/OSX developer wouldn't know about it.  `NSLog()` calls `[NSDate description]` and `description` formats the date in UTC timezone.  To show the date in a different time zone, set-up an `NSDateFormatter` (including the time zone) and use that to do date -> string conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Droppy

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSISO8601DateFormatter` if targeting iOS 10 and above. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter