# Date formatting using NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get date as`NSString`. I'm receiving date in the format **2017-05-05T04:42:44.954604Z**

Below is the code in which I'm trying to apply `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *newdate = [utcDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.Z"];
msgDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:newdate];
```

But `msgDate` is showing `nil`

Comment: Your utcDate is provided in ISO 8601 format. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558859/convert-iso-8601-to-nsdate

Comment: Another similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/swift-how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-tim

Comment: I think it's not said enough times, but write `2017-05-05T04:42:44.954604Z` and below write `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.Z`. What's wrong for the dateFormat to not match the string date? That will tell you your issue? What's about the "T"? How is it interpreted in your dateFormat? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 'SS' specifier (with number of S's equal to number of digits you want to get - 6 in your case)

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"];
```

instead of

```
 NSString *newdate = [utcDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.Z"];
```

**UPDATE**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"];
 NSDate *msgDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-05-05T04:42:44.954604Z"];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks

Comment: @MugheesMusaddiq - CHECK THE UPDATED ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ";// chang
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-04-13T05:57:44.886Z"];
NSString * msgDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
 // if get nil **date** try to change this time format
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #pragma mark- Change dateFormat method
 + (NSString*) changeDateFormat:(NSString*)date
 {
     NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

     [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];

     NSDate* fromDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY.MM.dd"];

     NSString* formatedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:fromDate];

     if (formatedDate == nil)
     {
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

         fromDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY.MM.dd"];

         formatedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:fromDate];

     }
     if (formatedDate == nil)
    {
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

          fromDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY.MM.dd"];

         formatedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:fromDate];

    }

    return formatedDate;

 }
```