# Parsing a date string containing a 'T' and + time zone offset

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter, date-parsing

I need to check on dates for certain items. I'm reading a string from a JSON file that looks like:

```
"revisionDate":"2013-08-28T13:07:53+00:00"
```

When I try to format it

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:revisionDateTime];
```

`date` is always nil. I think this is because of that `T` that's in that timestamp string. I don't know how to handle it, and there doesn't seem to be any mention how (at least that I can find), in [the reference I'm using](http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/nsdateformatter-formatting-strings-reference/).

Any ideas on how I can handle this?

Comment: Can you confirm that `revisionDate` is an `NSString`?

Comment: It's not just the "T", it's the time zone offset bit too. Possible duplicate of [Converting an ISO 8601 timestamp into an NSDate: How does one deal with the UTC time offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the `NSDateFormatter` instance to account for the `T`:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd T HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```

You may also want to consider encapsulating literal string values (in this case, dashes, spaces, colons, and the `T`) between quotes:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZ"]
```

Comment: You kind sir (or madam), are brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: In exactly 1 minute :)