# How to parse ISO 8601 date in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, iso

I need to create an NSDate from json, and the date in in a format I have never used. The date string I'm getting back is `2014-02-07T03:10:43.824Z`. Does anyone know the correct date format string I need to use for the date formatter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc?rq=1

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that the .824 was the miliseconds. You should put that in an answer so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
 //correcting format to include seconds and decimal place
 NSString* input = @"2014-02-07T03:10:59:434Z";
 dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
 // Always use this locale when parsing fixed format date strings
 NSLocale* posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
 dateFormat.locale = posix;
 NSDate* output = [dateFormat dateFromString:input];
```

Comment: @Rob, thanks, I've made edits

Comment: This did not work for me. The date format string that worked for me was `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: Try `'Z'` instead of `Z`

Comment: No, 'Z' would escape the Z character, which is not what we want. The Z in the timestamp is a valid character which indicates the UTC timezone (see [the UTC section here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)).

This is why [the answers on this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc?lq=1) use Z, not 'Z'.

Comment: The answer contains an error, the 'Z' should have been Z.