# Format NSString 2015-05-24T20:10:00.000Z to M/d, h:mma (5/24, 8:00PM)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an `NSString` `@"2015-05-24T20:10:00.000Z"`, and I am using an `NSDateFormatter` with the date format `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`, but it always returns `nil`.

I am using the following code, but the output is always (null).

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// NSString *input = @"2013-05-08T19:03:53+00:00";
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"]; //iso 8601 format
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dictScheduleData valueForKey:@"scheduledOn"]]; // coming from the server 2015-05-24T20:10:00.000Z
NSLog(@"Date output: %@", date);
```

Comment: How the date format you used match the `NSString` format you got?

Comment: Are you trying to get an NSDate object from an NSString? You might want to mention that you're using NSDateFormatter too (I assume your using NSDateFormatter). If you're using NSDateFormatter, I posted an answer below.

Comment: @Christophr I am having NSString @"2015-05-24T20:10:00.000Z from server I need to display it in the UILabel this format (5/24, 8:00PM)

Comment: Your question have been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc

Comment: For the second part, to convert it to (5/24, 8:00PM), you can change NSDateFormatter's dateFormat to "M/d, h:mma", then use NSDateFormatter's method stringFromDate. Then put that string in UILabel's text

Comment: But after setting dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ then dateFromString is always nil So later i can again setDateFormatter to "M/d, h:mma" to get desired output

Answer (score 2):

Try this dateFormat

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the string's date format. Use NSDateFormatter, then set the date format to match the string's date format. Then use dateFromString method.

to convert it to (5/24, 8:00PM), you can change NSDateFormatter's dateFormat to "M/d, h:mma", then use NSDateFormatter's method stringFromDate (the date you previously got, which should not be nil if done correctly). Then put that string in UILabel's text.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[timeFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString *DateString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
```